# Proving that $AB=BA$ means $A^mB^n = B^nA^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So given that $AB=BA$
Now we need to prove that this means $A^mB^n = B^nA^m$
So I attempt this by first proving $AB^n=B^nA$

So first when $n=1$
It is true as given $AB=BA$

Let $AB^n=B^nA$ be true

Now lets prove that $AB^{n+1}=B^{n+1}A$ is true

$AB^{n+1} = AB^nB = (B^nA)B$  as  $B^nA = AB^n$

$B^n(AB)$ [By Associative law]

and now as $AB = BA$

$B^n(AB) = B^n(BA) = B^{n+1}A$

By principle of mathematical induction we have $AB^{n} = B^{n}A$

Now by the same way we have prove $A^mB = BA^m$

Hence that $A^mB^n = B^nA^m$

Is this proving logical?? Is there better way to proving this using perhaps

$\sum_{i\neq j}{A_{ij}B_{ji}}$

or more of simple proving or is my proving suitable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $A$ and $B$ commute, then prove that so also do $A^m$ and $B^n$ for all positive integers $m$ and $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536625/if-a-and-b-commute-then-prove-that-so-also-do-am-and-bn-for-all-posit). Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24A%5EmB%5En%20%3D%20B%5EnA%5Em%24&p=1). Also, a very similar one, but limited to square matrices of order $n$, is [Test of matrix commutativity](/q/2202146).

Comment: Your double induction proof is perfectly fine.

Comment: @RyanBertrand FYI, there's also the converse question in [If $A^kB^l=B^lA^k$ for all $k,l>1$, is $AB=BA$?](/q/3166566).

Comment: Your proof is well done!